# Nested Array in JSON - JOIN using JSON_TABLE

Tags: oracle12c

Using Oracle 12c, I have a JSON structure as below:

```
{
    "class": {
        "students": [{
                "name": "Joe",
                "rollnum": 11,
                "homephone": 3211113312,
                "joined_on": "2016-03-01",
                "subjects": [{
                    "subject_id": 21,
                    "marks": 53
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 23,
                    "marks": 43
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 24,
                    "marks": 35
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 25,
                    "marks": 90
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 26,
                    "marks": 87
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Toe",
                "rollnum": 12,
                "homephone": 1231231122,
                "joined_on": "2016-03-01",
                "subjects": [{
                    "subject_id": 21,
                    "marks": 66
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 23,
                    "marks": 77
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 24,
                    "marks": 88
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 25,
                    "marks": 90
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 26,
                    "marks": 98
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Roe",
                "rollnum": 15,
                "homephone": 3332221111,
                "joined_on": "2016-03-01",
                "subjects": [{
                    "subject_id": 21,
                    "marks": 56
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 23,
                    "marks": 57
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 24,
                    "marks": 87
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 25,
                    "marks": 66
                }, {
                    "subject_id": 26,
                    "marks": 76
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

A class has multiple students and each student is enrolled to multiple subjects. This data is being stored as a JSON LOB structure in a table column. Now, when I try to join the SubjectID from the nested array to the Subject master table, it does not work. However, if I try to query for a particular subject (or others); it works perfectly fine.

Below is the query, I am using. Please help.

```
SELECT sjson.name,sjson.rollnum,sm.subject_name,sjson.marks
  FROM   
  students s, 
  JSON_TABLE(ss.student_json,'$.class.students[*]'
  columns(  
                                 name varchar2(50) path '$.name',
         rollnum number path '$.rollnum',
         homephone number path '$.homephone',
         joined_on varchar2 path '$.joined_on' ,
                nested path '$.subjects[*]' columns( 
                                subject_id number path '$.subject_id',
                                marks number path '$.marks'
        )
       ) 
  )sjson, 
  subject_master sm
  WHERE sjson.name = 'Joe'
  AND sjson.subject_id = sm.subject_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) table 'students' is aliases as 's' but the JSON_TABLE input refers to 'ss'. I assume this is just a type.

2) you do not explain what 'does not work' mean? Are you seeing no rows returned or an error message?

3) i tries your query (with minor changes) on 12.1.0.2 RELEASE and it appears to work:

```
create table subject_master (id number, name varchar2(20));

insert into subject_master values(21, 'a');
insert into subject_master values(23, 'b');
insert into subject_master values(24, 'c');
insert into subject_master values(25, 'd');
insert into subject_master values(26, 'e');

create table students (student_json clob);
insert into students values ('{
"class": {
    "students": [{
            "name": "Joe",
            "rollnum": 11,
            "homephone": 3211113312,
            "joined_on": "2016-03-01",
            "subjects": [{
                "subject_id": 21,
                "marks": 53
            }, {
                "subject_id": 23,
                "marks": 43
            }, {
                "subject_id": 24,
                "marks": 35
            }, {
                "subject_id": 25,
                "marks": 90
            }, {
                "subject_id": 26,
                "marks": 87
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Toe",
            "rollnum": 12,
            "homephone": 1231231122,
            "joined_on": "2016-03-01",
            "subjects": [{
                "subject_id": 21,
                "marks": 66
            }, {
                "subject_id": 23,
                "marks": 77
            }, {
                "subject_id": 24,
                "marks": 88
            }, {
                "subject_id": 25,
                "marks": 90
            }, {
                "subject_id": 26,
                "marks": 98
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Roe",
            "rollnum": 15,
            "homephone": 3332221111,
            "joined_on": "2016-03-01",
            "subjects": [{
                "subject_id": 21,
                "marks": 56
            }, {
                "subject_id": 23,
                "marks": 57
            }, {
                "subject_id": 24,
                "marks": 87
            }, {
                "subject_id": 25,
                "marks": 66
            }, {
                "subject_id": 26,
                "marks": 76
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

}');

```
SELECT sjson.name,sjson.rollnum,sm.name,sjson.marks
  FROM   
  students s, 
  JSON_TABLE(s.student_json,'$.class.students[*]'
  columns(  
                             name varchar2(50) path '$.name',
     rollnum number path '$.rollnum',
     homephone number path '$.homephone',
     joined_on varchar2 path '$.joined_on' ,
            nested path '$.subjects[*]' columns( 
                            subject_id number path '$.subject_id',
                            marks number path '$.marks'
    )
   ) 
 )sjson, 
 subject_master sm
 WHERE sjson.name = 'Joe'
 AND sjson.subject_id = sm.id;


NAME                              ROLLNUM
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
NAME              MARKS
-------------------- ----------
Joe                            11 
a                53

Joe                            11
b                43

...
```

Comment: Thanks Beda, this is what I have been trying on a different data-set for one of my clients. Apparently, my results weren't per expectations. I will try to co-relate and get back. What I found was, the SQL engine was not able to correctly realize the JOIN between a JSON nested column and the Subject Master table.